# How can I alert my squad to an event in Freeplay?

Tags: anthem

Often I play free play with a match made team of random team members.

The game on PC does not feature any team chat. So how can I notify the other players in my free play instance that there is a World Event or other thing happening at my position.

This is especially relevant right now with the Titans roaming in free play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current release `1.0.2.01 (347811)` it seems the only way is using a headset, to use the ingame VOIP communications.

On PC you can hold <kbd>T</kbd> to Push to talk by default.